# How do I write a Java program for random multiplcation?

Tags: java, random, percentage

Here is the question:
"Write a program that helps to teach elementary kids multiplication. The kids are asked to multiply 2
random numbers and provided an answer. The random numbers can range from 1 to 12. Once the
program has asked them 10 questions, it prints the percentage they got correct."
I know how to work with the random number method but I don't know how to ask the user this correctly.

Comment: Is this homework? If yes, could you have been taught this earlier?

Comment: Please show the work that you have done.  It's very unlikely that anyone will just give you the whole answer.  Yes this looks like your homework assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow doesn't exist to do your homework.
But I can give you some hints.

1. Create two random number
2. Calculate result
3. [Ask for the result](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-get-input-from-user-in-java)
4. Compare your result with the input (first check if it is a integer if not ask again)
5. Output if the student has entered the right answer.
6. Go back to step one